# Is hashCode of a scala enum is the same on different JVM (spark) ?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hashcode

I read that a good practice for enum is scala is as follow.

I deliberately extends the class with Serializable for Spark.

```
sealed abstract class MyEnum(val nature: String) extends Serializable
case object A extends MyEnum("a")
case object B extends MyEnum("b")
```

The problem is that i want that the enum should be **extensible by others**, thus i have to remove the sealed keyword to enable this functionality

```
abstract class MyEnum(val nature: String) extends Serializable
case object A extends MyEnum("a")
case object B extends MyEnum("b")
```

On another file

```
import enumpackage.MyEnum
case object C extends MyEnum("c")
```

Knowing this [issue](http://dev.bizo.com/2014/02/beware-enums-in-spark.html) with Java enum on Spark, i was wondering how is generate the hashCode from object that extends class that are sealed or not.

Is it safe to avoid sealed keyword for my purpose or do i have to keep it, why ?
If i have to keep it, is there any solution to my extensibility problem.

Answer (score 4):

In programming languages, particularly in Java & Scala enumerations are not extendible by the user, but only by the owner of the enumeration and usually for good reason, control. If you are getting rid of `sealed` then don't consider it an enumeration, just consider it just like any other class with subclasses or subobjects.

As for your `hashCode`. You get that automatically with `case class` or `case object`, so there is nothing extra you really need to do.